# Laplace equation for circular symmetry: given a potential $\phi (z,0)$, how to find $\phi (0,r)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, poissons-equation, potential-theory

The potential function $\phi(z,r)$ has circular symmetry with respect to $r$. It also satisfies the Laplace equation $\partial \phi^2/\partial z^2 + \partial \phi^2/\partial r^2 + (1/r)\partial \phi/\partial r = 0 $ in the source-free half space $z>0$.  Assume it is also well-behaved, i.e. differentiable and fades to zero at large $r$ or $z$.

It is often easy to derive the potential along the axis of symmetry, $\phi (z,0)$. For example, deriving the potential or field on the axis of a charged circular loop is straightforward. Given the constraint imposed by the Laplace equation and the circular symmetry, this knowledge should be sufficient to determine the potential along a radius, $\phi(0,r)$, or, more generally, the potential in the entire half-space, $\phi (z,r)$.

[3D illustration showing circular symmetry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0qBj.png)

The very simplest example might be $\phi (z,0) = 1/z$ which maps to $\phi (0,r) = 1/r$, corresponding to the potential from a point charge.  I'm interested in functions that decay more slowly, especially the integrals of 1/z like $\phi (z,0) = -log(1/z)$ and $\phi (z,0) = x-x.log(1/z)$.

Is there a simple method or mapping that allows one to go from the potential along the axis of circular symmetry, $r=0$, to the potential on the surface $z=0$, or, indeed, to anywhere in the half-space?

**[Edit] Another Example**
If I consider a line charge extending along the z<0 axis, the potential ends up with unmanageable infinities. However, the vertical field $\partial \phi/\partial z$ for z>0 is a little better behaved and decays as 1/z. More or less by trial and error, I have found a solution for $\partial \phi/\partial z$ and $\partial \phi/\partial r$ that I think satisfies the Laplace equation.

$\partial \phi/\partial z = 1/\sqrt(z^2+r^2)$ 
$\partial \phi/\partial r = (1-z/\sqrt(r^2+z^2))/r$

Subtituting:

$\partial/\partial z [1/\sqrt(z^2+r^2)] 
+ (1/r)\partial /\partial r[r.(1-z/\sqrt(r^2+z^2))/r] = 0 $

I'd like to be able to do this systematically rather than by guesswork.

Comment: You're asking for a harmonic function that's bounded everywhere?

Comment: @Aruralreader I've edited to add an example that makes it a bit clearer the sort of thing that prompted the interest.

Comment: Do you want the solution in a half-plane, or a circularly symmetric space?  If you want to solve the equation using polar coordinates, perhaps map the half-plane to the whole plane and then proceed there?

Comment: Usually, we would reserve $z$ for a complex variable, but no matter.  Let $w=z+ia$ or $w=a+i z,$ depending on which half-plane you are visualizing.  Then $\zeta=w^2$ maps the half-plane into the whole plane.

Comment: Better, yet.  The function $w = e^\zeta$ maps a strip into a half plane.  The solution in the strip is rather straight forward (a linear function).

Comment: @mjw thanks for the feedback.  I'm not understanding.  My coordinates have z as the axis of symmetry (i.e. r=0) and then the x,y plane perpendicular to that with r = sqrt(x^2+y^2).  Given the potential along z, I'm looking to find the potential along r.

Comment: Okay, my mistake, you have a 3D problem (along a cylinder)?!

Comment: [PlanetPhysics/Laplace Equation in Cylindrical Coordinates](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/PlanetPhysics/Laplace_Equation_in_Cylindrical_Coordinates)

Comment: @HandeBruijn that's an excellent reference, thanks.  I'll go ahead and mark Sal's answer as correct.  It's not quite what I was hoping for but it does seem like the expansion of the $\phi(z)$ function into an exponential  series and then summing the corresponding radial functions is a good approach, at least numerically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\underline{\text{Is the problem well posed?}} $

Specifying the potential $\phi(z)$ on $z>0$ is not enough to uniquely determine $V(r,z)$ in the space $z>0$. This is because the boundary data on the $z=0$ plane is missing. For example, consider the two potentials defined along the entire $z$ axis

$$
\phi_1(z)=1 \\
\phi_2(z)=\operatorname{sgn}(z)
$$

Where $\operatorname{sgn}$ is the sign function. For $z>0$ we have $\phi_1=\phi_2$, yet they lead to different potentials in all space (and consequently different potentials in the space $z>0$). To demonstrate the non-uniqueness, it is sufficient to look at the $z=0$ plane. $\phi_1$ leads to $V(r,0)\sim\ln(r)$ while symmetry dictates that $\phi_2$ leads to $V(r,0)=0$.

Laplace boundary value problems require boundary data on the full surface enclosing the volume of interest. As we are concerned with the half space $z>0$ here, part of that boundary is the $z=0$ plane. The problem is not well posed unless:

1. We specify boundary data on the $z=0$ plane.
2. We work in the full space and specify $V$ everywhere along the $z$ axis.
3. We specify a potential on $z>0$ that is a *complex analytic* function of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ (see below). This fails even for the point charge potential which is $1/|z| \neq 1/z$.

$\underline{\text{An integral representation}} $

If the specified potential $\phi(z)$ may be analytically continued to complex $z$, we have the following representation due to Poisson (see eg. [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1965-71-06/S0002-9904-1965-11400-8/S0002-9904-1965-11400-8.pdf))

$$ \tag{1}
V(r,z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi d\eta \ \phi(z+ir\cos\eta) 
$$

Which does what you are asking for$^\dagger$: generate $V$ in all space given $V$ along the $z$ axis. Let us verify that this representation satisfies the axisymmetric Laplace's equation $\nabla^2V=\partial_{zz}V+\partial_{rr}V+r^{-1}\partial_rV=0$. Upon taking derivatives we have

$$
\nabla^2V=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi d\eta \ \left[\phi''-\phi''\cos^2\eta+\frac{i \phi'}{r}\cos\eta \right]
$$

Integrating the third term by parts yields $-\phi'' \sin^2\eta$ (the boundary term vanishes as long $\phi'$ is finite at the integral bounds) and we are left with

$$
\nabla^2V=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi d\eta \ \phi'' \left[1-(\cos^2\eta+ \sin^2\eta) \right]=0
$$

By setting $r=0$ in (1) we may also verify that the candidate $V$ satisfies the boundary condition $V(0,z)=\phi(z)$

$$
V(0,z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi d\eta \ \phi(z) = \phi(z)
$$

Thus (1) is the unique solution to $V(r,z)$.

For the type of functions you are interested in, such as $\phi(z)=\ln(z) \neq \ln(|z|)$, you may need to worry about branch cuts while performing the integral. Finding $V(r,0)$ by setting $z=0$ in (1) simplifies things somewhat

$$
V(r,0)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi d\eta \ \phi(ir\cos\eta)
$$

For $\phi(z)=\ln(z)$, performing the integral yields

$$
V(r,0)=\ln(r/2)
$$

$\dagger$ Almost. The form of potential you specify on $z>0$ is continued to all $z$ when doing this.

$\underline{\text{The Neumann problem}} $

An alternative is to motivate physically plausible boundary data on the $z=0$ plane. Since you want to *find* $V(r,0)$, it wouldn't be useful to consider a Dirichlet condition on the $z=0$ plane. The examples you give, such as that of a point charge or disk suggest we apply the Neumann boundary condition $\partial_zV(r,0)=0$.

The simplest way to enforce this boundary condition is: given $\phi(z)$ for $z>0$, let $\psi(z)$ be the even continuation of $\phi$ to all $z$. Now we can work in the whole space and forget about the boundary condition at $z=0$.

Separation of variables for the axisymmetric Laplacian yields

$$ \tag{2}
V(r,z)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dk}{2\pi} \ A(k) I_0(|k|r)e^{ikz}
$$

Where $I_0$ is a modified Bessel function. The function $A(k)$ is determined by the boundary data at $r=0$

$$
V(0,z)=\psi(z)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dk}{2\pi} \ A(k) e^{ikz}
$$

Which we recognize as the Fourier transform of $\psi$

$$
A(k)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dz \ \psi(z) e^{-ikz}
$$

The $A(k)$ determine $V$ everywhere in space via (2). Since $\psi$ is even by construction, we have

$$
A(k)=2\int\limits_{0}^\infty dz \ \psi(z) \cos(kz)=2\int\limits_{0}^\infty dz \ \phi(z) \cos(kz)
$$

Finally, on the $z=0$ plane, we can write $V$ as

$$
V(r,0)=2\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dk}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^\infty  dz' \ \phi(z') I_0(|k|r) \cos(kz')
$$

Which is expressed only in terms of your specified potential $\phi(z)$ on $z>0$. Actually *performing* the integrals in closed form for various $\phi$ may be difficult.

$\underline{\text{Multipole expansion}} $

Outside of a finite charge distribution, we have the multipole expansion of the potential in inverse powers of $r$

$$
V(r)=\frac{q}{r} + \frac{p}{r^2} + \frac{Q}{r^3} + \dots 
$$

The coefficients $q$, $p$, $Q$, will not concern us here. What is important is that the potential decays algebraically in $r$ outside of a finite charge distribution. If you are studying potentials that scale like $\ln r$, then either your region is not source free, or your charge distribution is infinite in extent (eg on or below the $z=0$ plane the charge density is non-vanishing as $r \to \infty$).

Comment: thanks! that looks like a valuable answer. Let me take some time to digest and understand.

Comment: @RogerWood No problem! I will update my post tonight with a few additional thoughts

Comment: Would the downvoter please comment on the problem with my post? Suggest improvements?

Comment: I still think my question is well-posed.  Given that the space z>0 is source free.  It seems to me that, aside perhaps from some constants of integration, there is still a 1:1 mapping between $\phi(0,r)$ to $\phi(z,0).  If I take the 2D FFT at z=0 surface, it's real and circularly symmetric and I can translate it to any z by multiplying by exp(-k<sub>r</sub>z).  The response at r=0 (DC) is simply the integral over the FFT at whatever z I choose (i.e. the inverse FFT evaluated at r=0).  This lends itself to computation rather than analytic result and I wouldn't know how to run it backwards

Comment: Do you have a reference you can point me to for the "representation due to Poisson", please.  This seems connected somehow to the inverse Laplace transform assciated with the exp(-k<sub>r</sub>z) weighting function used to translate between z-planes.

Comment: Updated post with response. Are you imagining that your specified potential is eg. symmetric in $z$, even though you only specify it on $z>0$? If not it is easy to come up with a counterexample: you specify $\phi(z)$ on $z>0$. I then calculate the potential using an odd extension $\phi_{\text{odd}}(-z)=-\phi(z)$, which will ensure $V=0$ on the $z=0$ plane.

Comment: @RogerWood I've re-read your comment about Fourier transform several times, and I don't understand your argument. The problem is not that we cannot find *one* potential that satisfies your partial boundary condition along$z>0$, the problem is that we cannot find a *unique* potential that satisfies it.

Comment: If I specify the potential in the 2D plane as ϕ(0,r) = 1/r, doesn't that uniquely specify ϕ(z,r) = 1/sqrt(r^2+z^2) (the potential from an isolated charge at 0,0) and thus ϕ(z,0) = 1/z.  I admit it's not so clear to me the reverse mapping ϕ(z,0) ==> ϕ(0,r), is unique.  Let me try an add another example into my question.  I think I have a solution for a uniformly charged thin rod (BTW, I appreciate the discussion)

Comment: I understand your argument now. The reverse mapping, as you call it, is only unique if you specify the potential along the entire $z$ axis (the half axis $z>0$ is not the full boundary of the volume of interest). Meanwhile, the plane $z=0$ (together with a regularity condition at infinity) *does* provide a boundary to the volume of interest

Comment: Our edits crossed.  I've added another example.  I understand your point about the charge density becoming infinite. But a line charge should be ok for fields.  I agree that a narrow cone with linearly increasing net charge might be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

---

Starting over from the beginning ...

$$\frac{\partial \phi^2 }{\partial z^2} + \frac{\partial \phi^2}{\partial r^2 }+ \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r }= 0 $$

Letting $\phi(z,r)=\Phi(z) \Psi(r),$

$$
\Phi^{\prime \prime}(z)\Psi(r)+\Phi(z) \Psi^{\prime \prime}(r)+ \frac{1}{r} \Phi(z) \Psi^{\prime}(r)=0\\
%
\frac{\Phi^{\prime \prime}(z)}{\Phi(z)}+\frac{ \Psi^{\prime \prime}(r)+ \frac{1}{r}  \Psi^{\prime}(r)}{\Psi(r)}=0\\
%
$$
We can separate variables and write
$$
\frac{ \Psi^{\prime \prime}(r)+ \frac{1}{r}  \Psi^{\prime}(r)}{\Psi(r)}=-\frac{\Phi^{\prime \prime}(z)}{\Phi(z)}=-\lambda^2
$$

Resulting in two ordinary differential equations:
$$\Psi^{\prime \prime}(r)+ \frac{1}{r}  \Psi^{\prime}(r)+\lambda^2 \Psi(r)= 0 \\
 \Phi^{\prime \prime}(z)-\lambda^2 \Phi(z) =0
$$

To meet the boundary conditions, you can know express the solution as a Fourier series.

Comment: interesting point.  I'm assuming the half-space is source-free.  But I think you're pointing out that a potential of (a+b.log(r)).(c+dz) is a valid solution.  In terms of fields (gradient of potential), this would correspond to a constant z-field and radial field decaying as 1/r.  This is good to bear in mind - thanks!

Comment: I suppose we can't really assume the potential function is separable into a product like that and the z-dependence isn't really in the form I'm looking for.  But I don't know why the downvotes.  Your result does point to an interesting family of solutions where the z and r functions are linked by the single parameter, $\lambda$.  I assume $\lambda^2$ can even be a complex number?

Comment: That's typically what the textbooks recommend (separation of variables).  If not applicable, why not?  Also, $\lambda^2$ is assumed real to have a physically realizable solution.

Comment: As far as the down votes are concerned, could be constructive criticism if there were some comments or hints along with the votes.  Seems the author of the other question also is troubled by this.  Maybe somebody knows how to solve the problem but would rather just show how smart he is by voting on the answers?

Comment: I think as long as the real part of lambda is positive we're ok. The functions will be oscillatory but will trend to zero at z or r = infinity.  I worry that the simplest example (potential from an isolated charge) doesn't separate easily.  Though I see there's a nice example here where it does work well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392484/a-semi-infinite-right-circular-cylinder-problem?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the equation involving $r$ is a form of Bessel's equation, and the second equation involves solutions that are either hyperbolic cosines and hyperbolic sines, or equivalently exponentials with both positive and negative exponents.   Each set of solutions can be summed in a Fourier type series and can be matched to the boundary conditions (if they are specified).

Comment: @RogerWood We get one solution for each value of $\lambda$. The general solution is constructed by summing (integrating) over all possible $\lambda$, each weighted in a way that ensures the boundary conditions are met. The $1/|r|$ potential has the cylindrical expansion $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}=\frac{2}{\pi} \int\limits_0^\infty dk \ \cos(kz) K_0(kr)$

Comment: @Sal that gives me a better insight.  Let me take some time to digest all this.